# Not getting callback from google api, android?

Tags: gps

I have connected to google api for loaction in android. but i not getting any callback from google api. not getting location.
my code is

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    public static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
    private final String LOG_TAG = "logTagMngr";
    private TextView loactionout;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        loactionout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loactionout);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Turn on location?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Turn on Location", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            openWifiSettings();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();


        } else {
            googleApiClient.connect();

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public void openWifiSettings() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(500);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("AAA",location.toString());
        loactionout.setText(location.getLatitude()+"");
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("userLongitude",location.getLongitude()+"");
        editor.putString("userLatitude",location.getLatitude()+"");
        if(editor.commit()){
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Failed");
    }
}
```

i dont know the problem. not getting connection failed on suspended callbacks also. please help me.